# Share image to only twitter by intent.action_send error

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

I use code as follow to share image to twitter but when display screen of twitter app  to input text and image,it only display text ,image don't display.

```
public void shareImageByTwitter(Context mContext, String path) {
    File myFile = new File(path);
    final String[] twitterApps = {
            // package // name - nb installs (thousands)
            "com.twitter.android", "com.twidroid",
            "com.handmark.tweetcaster", "com.thedeck.android" };
    Intent tweetIntent = new Intent();
    tweetIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(myFile));
    final PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            tweetIntent,0);

    for (int i = 0; i < twitterApps.length; i++) {
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list) {
            String p = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (p != null && p.startsWith(twitterApps[i])) {
                tweetIntent.setPackage(p);

            }
        }
    }
    mContext.startActivity(tweetIntent);
}
```

How must I do.

Comment: Did you check the path is available to the Twitter application? It would not be the case if path is in your application cache folder